# Multiple collections in an array (session variable) — Property does not exist

Tags: arrays, laravel, session, object

I'am trying to fetch a session variable if the user is a guest. The variable is called "cart" and is set like this:

```
$product = new Collection((object) [
    'product_id' => $request->pId,
    'amount' => $request->amount,
    'variations' => $variations
]);

Session::push('cart', $product);
```

Then I later fetch it:

```
if(Auth::check()){
    $cartProducts = ShoppingCartItem::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
}else{
    $cartProducts = Session::get('cart');
}

foreach($cartProducts as $product){
    dd($product);
    $totalAmount += $product->amount;
    $totalPrice += (PriceHelper::getProductPrice($product->product->id, $product->amount));
}
```

The problem here is that `dd($product)` still outputs an array (the session variable array I assume) which means that for example `$product->amount` does not exist.

This is the output from `dd($product)`:

[image]

Comment: So the problem would be that even though you are logged in Auth::check() returns false (thus leading to this issue)?

Comment: No, that works fine. I'm trying to fetch my products in the cart from the session when I'm logged out which works fine. What doesn't work is that I can't use `$product->amount` even though "amount" is in the `$product` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either access the values using `get()`:

```
foreach ($cartProducts as $product) {
    $totalAmount += $product->get('amount');
    $totalPrice += PriceHelper::getProductPrice($product->get('product_id'), $product->get('amount'));
}
```

or as an array:

```
foreach ($cartProducts as $product) {
    $totalAmount += $product['amount'];
    $totalPrice += PriceHelper::getProductPrice($product['product_id'], $product['amount']);
}
```

or you could use `sum()` on the collection instead of using `foreach`:

```
$cartProducts = collect(Session::get('cart'));

$totalAmount = $cartProducts->sum('amount');
$totalPrice = $cartProducts->sum(function ($product) {
    return PriceHelper::getProductPrice($product['product_id'], $product['amount']);
});
```

**Edit**

For a quick fix if you need `$product` to be an object you could do something like:

```
$cartProducts = collect(Session::get('cart'))->map(function ($item) {
    return (object)$item->toArray();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works fine, thanks. But the problem is that I'd have to create two views (the cart view). One using for example `$product->title` (fproduct fetched from the database) and one using `$product["title"]` (product fetched from the session). Is it somehow possible to fetch values from that session array using the same notation (`$product->title`,...)?

Comment: @Scarwolf Ah, sorry I didn't realise you needed it to be an object. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Do you know if it is possbile to use the relationships somehow? For example my ShoppingCartItem Model has a relation to the product to fetch it's name, price etc. As I am saving the product id's in the Session is it somehow possible to do someting like `$product->product->title` where `$product` is not an Eloquent Model but some values including the product id stored in the session?

Comment: @Scarwolf Am I right in assuming that you have a `ShoppingCart` Model as well or is it just the `ShoppingCartItem` Model?

Comment: I do only have a `ShoppingCartItem` Model which referes to a product, a specific user (which would not be needed if stored in a session for guests) and also holds the amount of this product in the Cart. The model has a relationship with the product so that I can easily get the title of a product I've added to the cart.

Comment: @Scarwolf You could potentially new-up a `ShoppingCartItem` for every product in the cart, populate it will data from the session (don't save it) and the `Product` relationship should work fine as it'll be a `belongsTo` relationship which won't need to the `ShoppingCartItem` id. If you have quite a few products in the session cart and you want it to be more efficient then you could manually gets all the `Product`s from the cart and use `setRelation()` on the `ShoppingCartItem` model so you're not doing a separate query for every product.

Comment: You are my hero! The first idea is very smart and it finally worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Scarwolf Glad I could help! :)